# Hadoop recommissioning datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Do I need to delete all data from a datanode before recommissioning it, or it doesn't matter and the namenode will not pick stale data from the datanode?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your datanode to white list if you have one, set the master config on it, and start the service.
hadoop will take care of blocks by itself to match replication factor.